# Image Src url extraction using ms access vba ie navigation

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using MS Access code for VBA IE navigation. I want to extract image link value from below mentioned html code but unable to extract image link value.

HTML code is given below:

```
<div class="product-image-vp-sub">
    <div class="js-media-zoom-icons   hide-content">
        <div class="zoom product-zoom product-zoom-in js-zoom-in wmicon wmicon-zoom"></div> 
    </div>
    <img itemprop="image" src="http://ll-us-i5.wal.co/dfw/dce07b8c-3eca/k2-_f47f1f48-69bb-4277-9009-6f7d3a63697a.v2.jpg" class="product-image js-product-image js-product-primary-image" data-asset-id="2A5BB9FEFACA4EA09290025ED003ACAE" data-zoom-image="" alt="...And The Earth Did Not Swallow Him">
</div>
```

VBA code is given below.

```
Set html = ie.Document
my_data1 = html.getElementsByClassName("product-image-vp-sub")
For Each Item In my_data1
href1 = Item.getElementsByTagName("img")(0)
href2 = href1.src
Next
```